# How could I modify my for loop to display my dynamic divs in a bootstrap col-md-6 grid style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have all the JSON data appended to a wrapper right now, but the output displays 10 sections with 10 rows rather than all of the divs nested inside of one section tag and separated into 5 rows.  I can see the dynamically created elements when I inspect the page, but the JSON data won't display.  I feel like this is an easy fix and I'm missing something obvious.

```js
  
//Button on click function taken out for now
  //$(".btn").click(function(){
  //$('.flip').find(".card").toggleClass("flipped");
  //return false;
//});


//Api on load displays ten articles
window.onload = function() {

  API_Call.displayTenArticles();
 
};

  //Call to Api
  var API_Call = {

generateRandomSource: function(){

  // Array to store all external news sources from news API
  var allSources = ["abc-news-au", "al-jazeera-english","bbc-news", "bloomberg", "cnbc", "cnn", "google-news", "breitbart-news", "daily-mail", "reuters", "the-guardian-uk", "the-new-york-times", "the-wall-street-journal", "time", "the-washington-post"];
  // Var to store randomly generated number based off of length of allSources API
  var randomSource = Math.floor(Math.random() * allSources.length);
  // Selected newsource generated on onload
  var selectedSource = allSources[randomSource];
  // Function to select random news source
// Function to generate 10 images to DOM

return selectedSource;

},

//Function that displays 10 articles
displayTenArticles: function(){

selectedSource = API_Call.generateRandomSource();
  
// API_Call.NYT_API_Call(selectedSource);

API_Call.NEWS_API_Call(selectedSource); 

},

parse_Ajax_JSON: function(response){   
 let sectTemplate =
   `<section>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row></div>
 </div>`;

 let colTemplate =
   `<div class="col-md-6>
     <p><a class="post-link"></a></p>
        <div class="post-img-wrap">
            <img class="post-image">
        </div>
     <p class="post-description"></p>    
 </div>`;

 var results = response.articles;

 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i = i + 2) {
   let $sect = $(sectTemplate),
     $row = $sect.find('.row');

   $row.append(createPost(results[i]));
   // in case odd number entries, check if next item exists then append
   if (results[i + 1]) {
     $row.append(createPost(results[i + 1]));
   }
   // add whole section to dom
   $('#wrapper').append($sect);

 }

 function createPost(obj) {
   let $col = $(colTemplate);
   $col.find('.post-link').attr('href', obj.title).text(obj.title);
   $col.find('.post-image').attr('src', obj.urlToImage);
   //similar for description
   return $col;
 }

 function createPost(obj) {
   var $col = $(colTemplate);
   $col.find('.post-link').attr('href', obj.link).text(obj.title);
   $col.find('.post-image').attr('src', obj.urlToImage);
   $col.find('.post-description').attr('src', obj.urlToImage);
   //similar for description
   return $col;
   $('#wrapper').append('.post-image');
 }

},

//Api call to get data 
NEWS_API_Call: function(){

  var article = $(this).attr("data-name");
  var queryURL = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=" + selectedSource + "&sortBy=top&apiKey=01aed6729dc84b87b67d8eca2e2a711b"
  // ajax call to news API
  $.ajax({
    url:queryURL,
    method: 'GET',
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);

    API_Call.parse_Ajax_JSON(response);
  
  });

},

};
```

```css
/*
#558C89 Dark Green
#74AFAD Light Green
#D9853B Orange
#ECECEA Light grey



/*News Paper Font*/
@font-face{
  font-family: 'aflfont';
  src: url('aflfont.ttf');
}

/*-----Basic Setup-------*/
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

body#body1{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ECECEA ;
  height: auto; 
}

h1{
  padding-top:30px;
  margin:0;
}

h1.subscribeText{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'aflfont',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #D9853B;
  margin:0;
  padding: 10px;
}

p.pSubscribe{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'aflfont', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

hr{
  width: 30%;
}

.articleHeader{
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

section{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

p{
  margin:0;
}

a{
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'aflfont',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    color:#3544af;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styling of Container an Wrapper that holds the Articles */

.container{
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.row{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;

}

/*---- Header, Hero-Image, Logo, text, and Buttons  NewsLetter Form--*/
 header{
  background:#3544af;

} 
#logo{
  margin: 0;
}

.hero-image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: #74AFAD;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.hero-text{
  padding:50px 30px 0 30px;
}

p.headerText{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'aflfont', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.buttons{
  padding:40px 0 40px 0;
}
.btn1{
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'aflfont';
  background: #D9853B;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.btn2{
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff ;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'aflfont';
  background: #558C89 ;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.btn1:hover{
  color:#fff;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  background-color: #558C89;
}
.btn2:hover{
  color:#fff;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  background-color: #D9853B;
}
a.btn-primary:active{
  color: #3544af;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
/* Span to seperate buttons */
span{
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Article Nav Links and Buttons */
a{
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'aflfont',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    color:#3544af;
    text-decoration: none;
}

section.subscribe{
  margin-top:60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #558C89;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

input{
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  background:#ECECEA;
}

.subscribe-form{
  padding-top: 10px;
}

button.subscribe-submit{
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
  box-shadow: 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  background-color: #D9853B;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding:5px;
}
button.subscribe-submit:hover{
  color: #D9853B;
  transition: .5s ease-in;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/*-----Article Div Styling ---*/

/*Div that holds Article*/
#articleImage{
 text-align: center;
 background:#fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 padding-top: 20px;

}
/* Size of Dynamic loaded img*/
.imageSize{
  height: 450px;
  max-height: 450px;
}
/*Dynamic Description*/
p.description{
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 190%;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding:5px;
  font-family: 'aflfont', sans-serif;
}
/* Div for Dynmaic Title*/
#title{
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  border:2px solid #3544af;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}


/*----------Media Queries-----------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 790px){
#logo{
  width: 400px;
    
  }

/* Size of Dynamic loaded img*/
.imageSize{
  height: 450px;
  max-height: 450px;
}
/*Dynamic Description*/
p.description{
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 190%;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding:5px;
  font-family: 'aflfont', sans-serif;
}
/* Div for Dynmaic Title*/
#title{
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-left:2px solid #3544af;
  border-right:2px solid #3544af;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>SorceLess Home</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style.css">
 <link href="./assets/css/animate.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/waypoints.css">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body id="body1">

<header class="text-center">
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1><img class="os-animation" data-os-animation = "bounceInDown" data-os-animation-delay = ".1s" id="logo" src="./assets/img/sourceLesslogo.png"></h1>
    <p class="headerText os-animation" data-os-animation = "fadeInRight" data-os-animation-delay = ".2s">Moving beyond the biased opions <br>Opening up the mind to different views!</p>
  <section class="subscribe">
    <div class="subscribe-box os-animation" data-os-animation = "fadeInRight" data-os-animation-delay = ".2s">
      <h1 class="subscribeText">Subscribe</h1>
      <p class="pSubscribe">Subscribe to our newsletter to get the latest articles right to your inbox.<p>
    </div>
    <form action="index.html" method="post" class="subscribe-form os-animation" data-os-animation = "fadeInRight" data-os-animation-delay = ".2s">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Email address" autofocus>
      <button type="submit" class="subscribe-submit">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
      <div class="arrow bounce"></div>
  </section>
  </div>
</div>
</header>

<div class="container text-center">
 <div class="row buttons">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="os-animation" data-os-animation = "fadeInLeft" data-os-animation-delay = ".0s">
       <button class="btn1 btn-primary ">Articles</button><span><button class="btn2 btn-primary">Blogs</button></span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
 
<div id="wrapper" class="text-center os-animation" data-os-animation = "bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay = ".0s">
 </div><!--Wrapper, holds dynamic divs -->


</div><!--container -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script><!-- jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src=./assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js></script><!-- jQuery Animation-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src=./assets/js/waypoints.js></script><!-- js animation -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/app.js"></script><!-- Article Api -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment the `for()` loop by 2 each iteration. Add a section and row for each iteration and append multiple posts to that row

```
 let sectTemplate =
   `<section>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row></div>
 </div>`;

 let colTemplate =
   `<div class="col-md-6>
     <p><a class="post-link"></a></p>
        <div class="post-img-wrap">
            <img class="post-image">
        </div>
     <p class="post-description"></p>    
 </div>`;



 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i = i + 2) {
   let $sect = $(sectTemplate),
     $row = $sect.find('.row');

   $row.append(createPost(results[i]));
   // in case odd number entries, check if next item exists then append
   if (results[i + 1]) {
     $row.append(createPost(results[i + 1]));
   }
   // add whole section to dom
   $('#wrapper').append($sect);

 }

 function createPost(obj) {
   let $col = $(colTemplate);
   $col.find('.post-link').attr('href', obj.link).text(obj.title);
   $col.find('.post-image').attr('src', obj.urlToImage);
   //similar for description
   return $col;
 }
```

Comment: Awesome! I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, but for some reason, I can't get the data to show up on the page, only in the console.

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle, plunker or any other sandbox site that reproduces problem

Comment: I still think I'm missing something here to return the JSON data to display on the screen rather than just in the console.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me.  Can you explain what you're doing in each step so I can have better clarification and play around with it?

Comment: Be better if you create a demo. Or at least provide sample data so I can put in demo

Comment: I just submitted my JSON data that I get back.  I will make a JS Fiddle.